# Does the Oracle ODP use the Oracle Listener?

Tags: oracle, odp.net

Im using ODP.net for 11g with no connectivity problems but I turned off the oracle listener and was still able to connect and pull data.

Does the Oracle ODP use the Oracle Listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All remote connections need to go through a listener. Once connected, the listener may not be required again (but it isn't something you'd turn off).

Local connections don't require a listener, but it is good practice to go through the listener as it replicates the remote functionality.

How did you turn off the listener ? And is the database local or remote ?

---

It is unlikely (not impossible, but VERY unlikely) that the shortcut in the Windows menu is turning off the remote listener. I suspect you have a local Oracle DBMS install (possibly without an actual database, just the software) and you turned off the local listener. The remote listener will still be up and running. You don't need a local listener for a database connection.

Comment: The listener can be turned off using the shortcut in the start menu. The db is remote. So before i connected the first time i turned it off but still got through.

Comment: Thanks gary.I should have given a more detailed config earlier.
I am running a VM hosted Oracle DB on WS2008R2 and do my dev on the main machine. Thus, no local connections. I can turn off the listener with either the command lsnrctl.exe and stop or from the shortcut i mentioned. 
Neither state affects my connectability which is considered a bug. The same code is applied to all my ADO.NET adapters but only Oracle (so far) has this behaviour